# Is there a way to merge two data frames on their index, remove duplicate values in index, and then append columns which will be assigned properly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a list of the top people who buy from our company, as well as a list of the top sellers from whom we purchase. They look like this:

```
          money_received    muhney_adj  lbs lbs_adj trips   trader
account                     
XYZ 2556972.42  0.00    12860910.0  0   461 NaN
ABC 2541912.58  -80439.42   4918390.0   -29283  73  DB
ZXCV    1806438.66  -300.00 8726460.0   0   186 AS
KLJU    1602633.62  -27600.00   9174020.0   0   287 NaN
ASDF    1320914.19  0.00    364761.0    0   9   JK
```

and

```
account money_paid  muhney_adj  lbs lbs_adj trips   trader
XYZ     1566198.29  -553.57 2302200 -4500.0 58  DB
ABC     584055.93   -21998.49   2854607 -17401.0    272 JB
PLM     434250.78   -17528.26   2389424 -6700.0 94  JK
JNI     384354.07   -314.50 2188932 -1000.0 38  JB
```

The account column is the index in both dataframes. There is some overlap in the accounts, while there are some which only appear in one of the two dfs.
How can I join the two dfs into a new df that would have a layout like this:

```
index   account money_received  lbs_sold    sale_trips  money_paid  lbs_bought  purchase_trips
0   XYZ         2556972.42  12860910    461 1566198.29  2302200 58
1   ABC          2541912.58 4918390 73  584055.93   2854607 272
2   PLM          1806438.66 8726460 186 434250.78   2389424 94
```

I do not mind if there are many null values; however, I need to remove all duplicate account names.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When account exists in both, the top one takes precedence and below one is discarded? lbs_sold, sales_trips etc are not in either of the two DF. Need some more clarity to understand the question. Also, ASD doesn't exists in either of the two DFs.

Comment: The idea is that I have one dataframe for purchasing and one for selling. I'd like one unified df, where I could see all accounts I do business with, be it buying, selling, or both. I just renamed the lbs and trips columns i the model combined df, because in the native df, they have the same names. I also fixed the point about an example name appearing in what I want, but not the two starter dfs.

Comment: why ZXCV, KLJU, ASDF and JNI not in the resulting DF? considering PLM is only in second DF, but included in resulting DF. What is the criteria of including the account in the result

Comment: I am just trying to show what the layout of the three dfs looks like. There are many more rows for all three of them.

Comment: @jdfried provide dict for both df1 and df2 with "df.to_dict" and copy/paste the dicts here like this we can reproduce it in our IDE. And try to find an example with sample accounts ID who some of them match each other otherwise we won't be able to merge correctly.